# Django's EMAIL_PORT for google

Tags: python, django

On the DigitalOcean's site I saw  EMAIL_PORT = 465, then [here](http://www.mangooranges.com/2008/09/15/sending-email-via-gmail-in-django/) the port is 587  and I also saw somewhere 687. Whats the difference between all of them and how to choose a port ?

Comment: 465 is the SSL port, while 587 is the TSL one. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#email-use-tls

Comment: I was just there, but couldn't find that 465 is ssl just the EMAIL_USE_TLS boolean variable. Did you see it in there or u already knew that ?

Comment: Just google for gmail smtp ports